# perimeter of an eelipse

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

I am working with this document http://pages.pacificcoast.net/~cazelais/250a/ellipse-length.pdf

I have some trouble at the last few steps. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zh5xy6ykl5ukhx9/ellipse.png

how do we manipulate the first sum in this picture to get the sum in the second expression. I know how to do the final step but I can't understand how those two are equal. I know that we are factoring out pi/2 but that doesn't affect the sum at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because
$$\begin{align}2^n\cdot n!&=2^n\cdot\{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots\cdot(n-1)\cdot n\}\\&=2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots\cdot(2n-2)\cdot2n.\end{align}$$
Does this help?

Comment: Yes, however I am still having some trouble making the transition. But thank you this is the thing that I have the biggest trouble with. Some extra info like this helps

Comment: n!=n(n-1)! why do we have a term n(n-1) that is confusing me

Comment: What are you talking about? which part? You are talking about what I wrote?

Comment: 2^n*n!=2^n*(n(n-1)!) why do we get 2^n*(1*2*3*......(n-1)n). Sorry if this is a stupid question I am still in high school
......why (n-1) instead of (n-1)!

Comment: Do you understand $n!=1\cdot 2\cdots(n-1)\cdot n$? You can get what I wrote multiplying this by $2^n$.

Comment: $n!=n\cdot (n-1)!$. This is true. But you don't need to use this because $n!=1\cdot 2\cdots(n-1)\cdot n.$

Comment: ahaa now I get it thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Is everything fine in that transformation?

Comment: If you are asking if I understood it yes at least the part that you explained. I just want to ask you about the transition in the numerator. 1*3*5*....(2n-3)(2n-1)=1*3*5*...(2n-1) this happens because (2n-3) and (2n-1) will form the same number if we take the sum to infinity, since (2n-1) is just missing 1 which is implied because of the multiplication. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: NO. no ralation with infinity. $1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2n-1)=1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots(2n-3)(2n-1)$ because there is no difference. The $\cdots$ represents multiplying every odd. So, you can write whichever you want. But the latter may be somewhat better because it is easier to understand.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. I guess infinity is a bad way to say it I meant that the general term is the same because the first term of (2n-3) which is 1 is implied because 3*5*.......(2n-1) is the same as 1*3*5*........(2n-1). Thanks I understand this completely now and am confident in my reasoning as well